# php.ini variable not set through htaccess

Tags: php, php-ini

Which php.ini variables we can not set through phpfiles or with htaccess.

Means if we want to set the variable then we have to directly configure at php server files.

can anyone give me list of that variables name?

Comment: suppose checking the manual for yourself was just to much work.

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Check the "Changeable" column

Answer (score 2):

The complete list is very long. You can check this page [List of php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) for help. Those with the `PHP_INI_` in the `Changeable` column you need to see.

```
allow_call_time_pass_reference
allow_url_fopen
allow_url_include
always_populate_raw_post_data
apc.cache_by_default
apc.enabled
apc.enable_cli
apc.file_update_protection
apc.filters
apc.gc_ttl
apc.include_once_override
apc.localcache
apc.localcache.size
apc.max_file_size
apc.mmap_file_mask
apc.num_files_hint
apc.optimization
apc.report_autofilter
apc.rfc1867
apc.rfc1867_freq
apc.rfc1867_name
apc.rfc1867_prefix
apc.shm_segments
apc.shm_size
apc.slam_defense
apc.stat
apc.stat_ctime
apc.ttl
apc.user_entries_hint
apc.user_ttl
apc.write_lock
apd.bitmask
apd.dumpdir
apd.statement_tracing
arg_separator
arg_separator.input
arg_separator.output
asp_tags
assert.active
assert.bail
assert.callback
assert.quiet_eval
assert.warning
async_send
auto_append_file
auto_detect_line_endings
auto_globals_jit
auto_prepend_file
axis2.client_home
axis2.enable_exception
axis2.enable_trace
axis2.log_path
bcmath.scale
bcompiler.enabled
birdstep.max_links
blenc.key_file
browscap
cgi.check_shebang_line
cgi.discard_path
cgi.fix_pathinfo
cgi.force_redirect
cgi.nph
cgi.redirect_status_env
cgi.rfc2616_headers
child_terminate
cli.pager
cli.prompt
cli_server.color
coin_acceptor.autoreset
coin_acceptor.auto_initialize
coin_acceptor.auto_reset
coin_acceptor.command_function
coin_acceptor.delay
coin_acceptor.delay_coins
coin_acceptor.delay_prom
coin_acceptor.device
coin_acceptor.lock_on_close
coin_acceptor.start_unlocked
com.allow_dcom
com.autoregister_casesensitive
com.autoregister_typelib
com.autoregister_verbose
com.code_page
com.typelib_file
crack.default_dictionary
daffodildb.default_host
daffodildb.default_password
daffodildb.default_socket
daffodildb.default_user
daffodildb.port
date.default_latitude
date.default_longitude
date.sunrise_zenith
date.sunset_zenith
date.timezone
dba.default_handler
dbx.colnames_case
default_charset
default_mimetype
default_socket_timeout
define_syslog_variables
detect_unicode
disable_classes
disable_functions
display_errors
display_startup_errors
docref_ext
docref_root
doc_root
enable_dl
engine
error_append_string
error_log
error_prepend_string
error_reporting
etpan.default.charset
etpan.default.protocol
exif.decode_jis_intel
exif.decode_jis_motorola
exif.decode_unicode_intel
exif.decode_unicode_motorola
exif.encode_jis
exif.encode_unicode
exit_on_timeout
expect.logfile
expect.loguser
expect.timeout
expose_php
extension
extension_dir
fastcgi.impersonate
fastcgi.logging
fbsql.allow_persistant
fbsql.allow_persistent
fbsql.autocommit
fbsql.batchSize
fbsql.batchsize
fbsql.default_database
fbsql.default_database_password
fbsql.default_host
fbsql.default_password
fbsql.default_user
fbsql.generate_warnings
fbsql.max_connections
fbsql.max_links
fbsql.max_persistent
fbsql.max_results
fbsql.mbatchSize
fbsql.show_timestamp_decimals
file_uploads
filter.default
filter.default_flags
from
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning
geoip.custom_directory
geoip.database_standard
gpc_order
hidef.ini_path
highlight.bg
highlight.comment
highlight.default
highlight.html
highlight.keyword
highlight.string
html_errors
htscanner.config_file
htscanner.default_docroot
htscanner.default_ttl
htscanner.stop_on_error
http.allowed_methods
http.allowed_methods_log
http.cache_log
http.composite_log
http.etag.mode
http.etag_mode
http.force_exit
http.log.allowed_methods
http.log.cache
http.log.composite
http.log.not_found
http.log.redirect
http.ob_deflate_auto
http.ob_deflate_flags
http.ob_inflate_auto
http.ob_inflate_flags
http.only_exceptions
http.persistent.handles.ident
http.persistent.handles.limit
http.redirect_log
http.request.datashare.connect
http.request.datashare.cookie
http.request.datashare.dns
http.request.datashare.ssl
http.request.methods.allowed
http.request.methods.custom
http.send.deflate.start_auto
http.send.deflate.start_flags
http.send.inflate.start_auto
http.send.inflate.start_flags
http.send.not_found_404
hyerwave.allow_persistent
hyperwave.allow_persistent
hyperwave.default_port
ibase.allow_persistent
ibase.dateformat
ibase.default_charset
ibase.default_db
ibase.default_password
ibase.default_user
ibase.max_links
ibase.max_persistent
ibase.timeformat
ibase.timestampformat
ibm_db2.binmode
ibm_db2.i5_allow_commit
ibm_db2.i5_dbcs_alloc
ibm_db2.instance_name
iconv.input_encoding
iconv.internal_encoding
iconv.output_encoding
ifx.allow_persistent
ifx.blobinfile
ifx.byteasvarchar
ifx.charasvarchar
ifx.default_host
ifx.default_password
ifx.default_user
ifx.max_links
ifx.max_persistent
ifx.nullformat
ifx.textasvarchar
ignore_repeated_errors
ignore_repeated_source
ignore_user_abort
imlib2.font_cache_max_size
imlib2.font_path
implicit_flush
include_path
ingres.allow_persistent
ingres.array_index_start
ingres.blob_segment_length
ingres.cursor_mode
ingres.default_database
ingres.default_password
ingres.default_user
ingres.max_links
ingres.max_persistent
ingres.report_db_warnings
ingres.timeout
ingres.trace_connect
ircg.control_user
ircg.keep_alive_interval
ircg.max_format_message_sets
ircg.shared_mem_size
ircg.work_dir
last_modified
ldap.base_dn
ldap.max_links
log.dbm_dir
log_errors
log_errors_max_len
magic_quotes_gpc
magic_quotes_runtime
magic_quotes_sybase
mail.add_x_header
mail.force_extra_parameters
mail.log
mailparse.def_charset
maxdb.default_db
maxdb.default_host
maxdb.default_pw
maxdb.default_user
maxdb.long_readlen
max_execution_time
max_input_nesting_level
max_input_vars
max_input_time
mbstring.detect_order
mbstring.encoding_translation
mbstring.func_overload
mbstring.http_input
mbstring.http_output
mbstring.internal_encoding
mbstring.language
mbstring.script_encoding
mbstring.strict_detection
mbstring.substitute_character
mcrypt.algorithms_dir
mcrypt.modes_dir
memcache.allow_failover
memcache.chunk_size
memcache.default_port
memcache.hash_function
memcache.hash_strategy
memcache.max_failover_attempts
memory_limit
mime_magic.debug
mime_magic.magicfile
msql.allow_persistent
msql.max_links
msql.max_persistent
mssql.allow_persistent
mssql.batchsize
mssql.charset
mssql.compatability_mode
mssql.connect_timeout
mssql.datetimeconvert
mssql.max_links
mssql.max_persistent
mssql.max_procs
mssql.min_error_severity
mssql.min_message_severity
mssql.secure_connection
mssql.textlimit
mssql.textsize
mssql.timeout
mysql.allow_persistent
mysql.connect_timeout
mysql.default_host
mysql.default_password
mysql.default_port
mysql.default_socket
mysql.default_user
mysql.max_links
mysql.max_persistent
mysql.trace_mode
mysqli.default_host
mysqli.default_port
mysqli.default_pw
mysqli.default_socket
mysqli.default_user
mysqli.max_links
mysqli.reconnect
namazu.debugmode
namazu.lang
namazu.loggingmode
namazu.sortmethod
namazu.sortorder
nsapi.read_timeout
oci8.default_prefetch
oci8.max_persistent
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics
oci8.persistent_timeout
oci8.ping_interval
oci8.privileged_connect
oci8.statement_cache_size
odbc.allow_persistent
odbc.check_persistent
odbc.defaultbinmode
odbc.defaultlrl
odbc.default_db
odbc.default_pw
odbc.default_user
odbc.max_links
odbc.max_persistent
odbtp.datetime_format
odbtp.detach_default_queries
odbtp.guid_format
odbtp.interface_file
odbtp.truncation_errors
opendirectory.default_separator
opendirectory.max_refs
opendirectory.separator
open_basedir
oracle.allow_persistent
oracle.max_links
oracle.max_persistent
output_buffering
output_handler
pam.servicename
pcre.backtrack_limit
pcre.recursion_limit
pdo.dsn.*
pdo_odbc.connection_pooling
pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name
pfpro.defaulthost
pfpro.defaultport
pfpro.defaulttimeout
pfpro.proxyaddress
pfpro.proxylogon
pfpro.proxypassword
pfpro.proxyport
pgsql.allow_persistent
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent
pgsql.ignore_notice
pgsql.log_notice
pgsql.max_links
pgsql.max_persistent
phar.extract_list
phar.readonly
phar.require_hash
enable_post_data_reading
post_max_size
precision
printer.default_printer
python.append_path
python.prepend_path
realpath_cache_size
realpath_cache_ttl
register_argc_argv
register_globals
register_long_arrays
report_memleaks
report_zend_debug
request_order
runkit.internal_override
runkit.superglobal
safe_mode
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars
safe_mode_exec_dir
safe_mode_gid
safe_mode_include_dir
safe_mode_protected_env_vars
sendmail_from
sendmail_path
serialize_precision
session.auto_start
session.bug_compat_42
session.bug_compat_warn
session.cache_expire
session.cache_limiter
session.cookie_domain
session.cookie_httponly
session.cookie_lifetime
session.cookie_path
session.cookie_secure
session.entropy_file
session.entropy_length
session.gc_dividend
session.gc_divisor
session.gc_maxlifetime
session.gc_probability
session.hash_bits_per_character
session.hash_function
session.name
session.referer_check
session.save_handler
session.save_path
session.serialize_handler
session.use_cookies
session.use_only_cookies
session.use_trans_sid
session_pgsql.create_table
session_pgsql.db
session_pgsql.disable
session_pgsql.failover_mode
session_pgsql.gc_interval
session_pgsql.keep_expired
session_pgsql.sem_file_name
session_pgsql.serializable
session_pgsql.short_circuit
session_pgsql.use_app_vars
session_pgsql.vacuum_interval
short_open_tag
simple_cvs.authMethod
simple_cvs.compressionLevel
simple_cvs.cvsRoot
simple_cvs.host
simple_cvs.moduleName
simple_cvs.userName
simple_cvs.workingDir
SMTP
smtp_port
soap.wsdl_cache
soap.wsdl_cache_dir
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled
soap.wsdl_cache_limit
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl
sql.safe_mode
sqlite.assoc_case
sybase.allow_persistent
sybase.hostname
sybase.interface_file
sybase.login_timeout
sybase.max_links
sybase.max_persistent
sybase.min_client_severity
sybase.min_error_severity
sybase.min_message_severity
sybase.min_server_severity
sybase.timeout
sybct.allow_persistent
sybct.deadlock_retry_count
sybct.hostname
sybct.login_timeout
sybct.max_links
sybct.max_persistent
sybct.min_client_severity
sybct.min_server_severity
sybct.packet_size
sybct.timeout
sysvshm.init_mem
tidy.clean_output
tidy.default_config
track_errors
track_vars
unserialize_callback_func
uploadprogress.file.filename_template
upload_max_filesize
max_file_uploads
upload_tmp_dir
url_rewriter.tags
user_agent
user_dir
user_ini.cache_ttl
user_ini.filename
valkyrie.auto_validate
valkyrie.config_path
variables_order
velocis.max_links
vld.active
vld.execute
vld.skip_append
vld.skip_prepend
windows_show_crt_warning
xbithack
xdebug.auto_profile
xdebug.auto_profile_mode
xdebug.auto_trace
xdebug.collect_includes
xdebug.collect_params
xdebug.collect_return
xdebug.collect_vars
xdebug.default_enable
xdebug.dump.COOKIE
xdebug.dump.ENV
xdebug.dump.FILES
xdebug.dump.GET
xdebug.dump.POST
xdebug.dump.REQUEST
xdebug.dump.SERVER
xdebug.dump.SESSION
xdebug.dump_globals
xdebug.dump_once
xdebug.dump_undefined
xdebug.extended_info
xdebug.idekey
xdebug.manual_url
xdebug.max_nesting_level
xdebug.output_dir
xdebug.profiler_aggregate
xdebug.profiler_append
xdebug.profiler_enable
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger
xdebug.profiler_output_dir
xdebug.profiler_output_name
xdebug.remote_autostart
xdebug.remote_enable
xdebug.remote_handler
xdebug.remote_host
xdebug.remote_log
xdebug.remote_mode
xdebug.remote_port
xdebug.show_exception_trace
xdebug.show_local_vars
xdebug.show_mem_delta
xdebug.trace_format
xdebug.trace_options
xdebug.trace_output_dir
xdebug.trace_output_name
xdebug.var_display_max_children
xdebug.var_display_max_data
xdebug.var_display_max_depth
xmlrpc_errors
xmlrpc_error_number
xmms.path
xmms.session
y2k_compliance
yami.response.timeout
yaz.keepalive
yaz.log_file
yaz.log_mask
yaz.max_links
zend.enable_gc
zend.multibyte
zend.script_encoding
zend.signal_check
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode
zend_extension
zend_extension_debug
zend_extension_debug_ts
zend_extension_ts
zlib.output_compression
zlib.output_compression_level
zlib.output_handler
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see list of variables here

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

And The "Changeable" column there shows the modes determining when and where a directive may be set.

The url is

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Answer (score -1):

Check [List of php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), and the `Changeable` field.